# Get dynamic values ​of dynamic arrays in a mode

Tags: php, laravel

I want to obtain the data of an **Audit** model, that within its columns **old_values** ​​and **new_values** ​​are stored arrays, but dynamic. When I do the `foreach` in the view it gives me the following error when wanting to show these columns:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: H:\DAF\resources\views\audit\index.blade.php)

I've already searched several blogs and they say how to do something similar but with static arrays, not with dynamic ones.

The **Audit** model is `Laravel's vendor` to audit called `OwenIt\Auditing`.

```
class Audit extends Model implements \OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Audit
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Audit;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'old_values'   => 'json',
        'new_values'   => 'json',
        'auditable_id' => 'integer',
    ];
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit;

class EstaticasController extends Controller {
    public function audit() {
        $audit = Audit::orderBy( 'id', 'DESC' )->get();
        return view( 'audit.index', compact( 'audit' ) );
    }
}
```

**Vista**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-stripped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Operaci&oacute;n</th>
                    <th>Tupla</th>
                    <th>Tabla</th>
                    <th>Valores antiguos</th>
                    <th>Valores Actuales</th>
                    <th>URL</th>
                    <th>IP</th>
                    <th>Creado</th>
                    <th>Actualizado</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php $no = 1 ?>
                @foreach($audit as $item)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->event }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->auditable_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->auditable_type }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->old_values }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->new_values }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->url }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->ip_address }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->created_at }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->updated_at }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Image of Table**
[image]

**Image of DB with data**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the issue:

```
// ...
// <td>{{ $item->auditable_type }}</td>
   <td>{{ $item->old_values }}</td>
   <td>{{ $item->new_values }}</td>
// <td>{{ $item->url }}</td>
// ...
```

The problem here is that, in order to print them in screen, the front-end is expecting the value to be string, but you are giving it an array. That's why the error is throw:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: H:\DAF\resources\views\audit\index.blade.php)

To solve it, you just have to iterate over the array to print every element of it:

```
@foreach ($item->old_values as $value)
    <p>{{ $value }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: what is the output when you `dd($this->old_values)`?

Comment: that gives me an empty array.

Comment: @Y1LY the values are stored as json in your database? if so, change your `$casts` config to this: `$casts = ['old_values' => 'array', 'new_values' => 'array']`

Comment: let's do and now I give you an answer

Comment: do you have records in your DB xd? try: `dd($item);`

Comment: I will publish a capture, above in my question, of what I get

Comment: now, do this before the `return` statement of your controller: `dd($audit->first()->toArray());`

Comment: the dd gave me back this:  ` array:14 [▼
  "id" => 32
  "user_type" => "App\User"
  "user_id" => "1"
  "event" => "created"
  "auditable_id" => 16
  "auditable_type" => "App\Models\Generador"
  "old_values" => []
  "new_values" => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Eólico Merbis 2"
    "id" => 16
  ]
  "url" => "http://localhost:8000/nomenclador/generador?"
  "ip_address" => "127.0.0.1"
  "user_agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 ..."
  "tags" => null
  "created_at" => "2019-02-13 15:59:51"
  "updated_at" => "2019-02-13 15:59:51"
]`